# Defining dataTypes in Cassandra Column Family

Tags: database-design, nosql, cassandra

```
create column family testing
  with key_validation_class = 'SomeType1'
  and comparator = 'SomeType2'
  and default_validation_class = 'SomeType3'
```

What do these represent here in this line.

```
set testing[a][b] = c
```

Is my perspective correct ?

```
a is of type SomeType1 
SomeType2 is how columns are sorted / sliced.
c is of type SomeType3
```

My goal is to create a store to contain time-series data

```
testing[a][b] = c;
a is of type 'String' or 'UTF8Type'
b is 'LongType'
c is 'FloatType'
```

I should be able to do

```
set testing['stats.randomNumber'][123456789] = 0.56;
set testing['stats.randomNumber'][123456790] = 90.33;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your cassandra-cli statement `set testing[a][b] = c`

`a` represent your rowkey

`b` represent your column name

`c` represent your column value

For further clarification regarding cassandra-cli see [Cassandra Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraCli)